# ASP.NET MVC Html.BeginRouteForm does not call the action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following route defined in my RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "VehicleAdvancedSearchResult",
    url: "search-result/{SearchTypeSlug}/{Condition}/{MakeSlug}/{ModelName}/{ModelExt}/{CategorySlug}/{ParishSlug}/{YearRange}/{PriceRange}",
    defaults: new
    {
       controller = "SearchResult",
       action = "VehicleAdvanceSearch",
       searchTypeSlug = UrlParameter.Optional,
       cond = UrlParameter.Optional,
       makeSlug = UrlParameter.Optional,
       model = UrlParameter.Optional,
       modelExt = UrlParameter.Optional,
       cat = UrlParameter.Optional,
       parishSlug = UrlParameter.Optional,
       yearRange = UrlParameter.Optional,
       priceRange = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

Inside a partial view I have this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginRouteForm("VehicleAdvancedSearchResult", new { controller = "SearchResult", action = "VehicleAdvanceSearch" })) {
   ...
   <input type="submit" value="Search &raquo;" class="btn btn-clc-theme-green medium white-text" />
<%}%>
```

Here is the Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult VehicleAdvanceSearch(
            string SearchTypeSlug,
            string Condition,
            string MakeSlug,
            string ModelName,
            string ModelExt,
            string ParishSlug,
            string CategorySlug,
            string YearRange,
            string PriceRange,
            string pages)
        {
   // Code here...
}
```

I am expecting the above method to be called when I click on the Submit button but it is not. When the button is clicked I want the `URL` to be prepared like defined in `RouteConfig.cs`.

What is the right method of doing this?

Comment: Only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: Was that the reason the action is not being called? Sorry for asking! I am not at my PC right now to fix the code and see if this works.

Comment: Not sure (cannot test myself now) - just pointing out that only the last parameter can be optional

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will fix the code and test. Will let you know what I get.